# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to store an image in firebase but I get this error MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
When I try a second time after it I get this error PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)

this is the function to upload the image

```
Future getImage_() async{
      final image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      setState(() {
        _image = File(image.path) ;
      });
    }
```

```
Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60 , ),
     child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
           iconSize: 30,
           onPressed: () { getImage_(); },
          ),
    ),
```